# Resolving relative url paths with PHP headers

Tags: php, url, header-files, relative-path

I am currently stuck trying to pass relative url paths through my header.php file.

My header file has the Navbar and the CSS/JS files, however when moving up the tree the url paths no longer work. I have a complex structure of subfolders that requires a more dynamic way to generate navbar and css stylesheet links.

How can I link navbar links and stylesheets with some dynamic script that generates the absolute path to the file?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use root relative paths?

If the css files are in a css directory in your web site's root directory, prefix the paths with a slash:

```
<link href="/css/style.css" />
```

If the current domain is http://example.org then `/css/style.css` will always reference http://example.org/css/style.css so it makes no difference where `/css/style.css` is specified.

Comment: If the page containing the CSS path is not at the same level as the path in the php script the CSS path will not work. My CSS path is on a header.php file so it will print the same content wherever the script is posted.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, this will always refer to the same file, as it's relative to your web root directory, not your script location...

Comment: The css path in the php script is referenced for files at the root level. However if that same script is within a folder that prefix will no longer work I will have to use a ../ The problem I have is that I want that script to rewrite that prefix depending on where the file is.

Comment: No, that's not how root relative paths work.  If the current domain is `http://example.org` then `/css/style.css` will always reference `http://example.org/css/style.css`.

Comment: I have a header.php with my css path: <link href="assets/css/gaia.css" rel="stylesheet"/> pages within the same level work, however on pages on a subdirectory the link cannot refer to the css because it is not on the same level.

Comment: That makes no difference, root relative paths have nothing to do with scripts or script paths...  Use the root relative path to gaia.css and it will always work

Comment: If I want to use a global header with that css file in it, it does matter.

Comment: no, it doesn't lol.  You clearly don't understand enough about this, please do some more research.  I don't know how many times I have to repeat this..

Comment: I think you didn't understand my issue. Root relative paths don't work in a default macos localhost setup. Don't worry I already solved this issue.

Comment: @tokyographer I don't think there's any such thing as a default setup with PHP.  If you don't give environmental information in your question, it's unknown to answerers.